# Add own HTML element to webpage with Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, element

I would like to change the html of an webpage and add an element.

Before:
div
p something /p
/div

After:
div
form
p something /p
/form
/div

Is this possible? Would be very happy, if someone answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the page with js, just use the `execute_script` function of your web driver in Selenium, modifying the DOM to insert whatever you want wherever you want in JS:

```
js = """var node = document.createElement("div");
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Example");
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("someIDOnPage").appendChild(node);  
"""
driver.execute_script(js)
```